# How can I download php file with source?

Tags: php

This is my demo url 
http://www.example.com/example.php

If we want to download example.php file with source code how can we do it?Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, no. You cant download PHP Source Code without access to the host.

Comment: Any other options. Without host access..

Comment: No, of course not. Server-side code often contains secret, sensitive, or proprietary information. If you could just download it, you could (for example) steal Facebook's code, or break into your credit card processor.